# How to create a wikipage with the design of a new page model?

Tags: sharepoint-online, online

I want to use a wikipagelibrary. Only when I create a new page in the wikipagelibrary I just get a empty page. But what I would like is a wikipage with the desing of a new page model (the one with the banner on top). Is that possible?

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new site content type which make the wiki page content type as parent.

Then upload custom template via Advanced settings of the newly created content type> upload a new document template.